# Keydown and Mouse down together, different actions

Tags: mouseevent, keydown, mousedown

Im trying to change the cursor on differnet actions. Essentially like panning a map.
Default: Standard pointer cursor
Shift Press: Grab Cursor
Shift + Left Click(hold/dragging): Grabbing Cursor

However, this works great until i start to move, which then my cursor jumps back to Grab instead of staying on grabbing. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
  //spacebar = 8
    if (event.keyCode == 16) {

        $('#mysvg').css('cursor', '-webkit-grab');

        }
});
$(document).keyup(function(event){
  //spacebar = 8
    if (event.keyCode == 16) {

        $('#mysvg').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } 
});



$( "#mysvg" ).mousedown(function(event){
      if (event.shiftKey) {
          $('#mysvg').css('cursor', '-webkit-grabbing');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keydown fires repeatedly in many browsers until you lift the key. I know Chrome and Firefox have this behavior. So your keydown handler is resetting the cursor.

Comment: Thanks...This is correct. I solved the problem by setting a flag in the keydown function.